# Is it possible to force an app to use cellular data instead of WiFi using android 7?

Tags: samsung

Is it possible to force an app to use cellular data instead of WiFi, using android 7 on samsung experience version 8.1?

Comment: Just turn off wifi and it'll use data. No? If that's not what you're asking, please edit your question to include more details

Comment: that only works some times and for a short while

Comment: That's why I'm not sure I understand the question. If your using YouTube for example, and you want it to use data instead of wifi, then simply turn off wifi. But if you're talking about an app that needs WiFi to function, but you want to fool it and make it seem that you're using WiFi, then you should edit your question to include that info

Answer (score 0):

Try [norootfirewall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.firewall).

It allows you to blacklist specific applications.